# How to Create a Dictionary Merging Values Based on Keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to create a dictionary mapping a keys to merged values.
Let's say I got key value pairs with a duplicated key `40`: `{40: "lamb"}`, `{40: "dog"}`, `{50: "chicken"}`

```
list_key = (40, 40, 50)
new_value = ("lamb", "dog", "chicken")

new_dict = {}
for i in list_key:
    if i not in new_dict:
        new_dict[list_key] = new_value
    else:
        new_dict[?] = new_value

return new_dict
```

This is where I get stuck.

What i need is `{40: ("lamb", "dog"), 50: ("chicken")}`.
How can I get this?

Comment: One way is to create a list if the key doesn't exist. Then, just append to that list whenever you encounter a relevant key.

Comment: It is not about merging... just creating a dictionary mapping an `int` key to `set`/`list` of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to create a list if the key doesn't exist. Then, just append to that list whenever you encounter a relevant key.

```
keys = [40, 40, 50]
values = ["lamb", "dog", "chicken"]
d = {}

for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    if k not in d:
        d[k] = []
    d[k].append(v)
```

...Though you can do this more prettily with `collections.defaultdict`:

```
keys = [40, 40, 50]
values = ["lamb", "dog", "chicken"]
d = defaultdict(lambda: [])

for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    d[k].append(v)
```