# Searching and Filtering List of Tuples in Python

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples, I'm trying to remove duplicates based on minimum value :

```
a_list = [("1","111","15"),("2","111","10"),("3","111","5"),("4","112","40"),("5","112","10")]

Output : 
id id_client value2
1   111         15
2   111         10
3   111         5
4   112         40
5   112         10

Required Output
id id_client value2
3   111         5
5   112         10
```

I tried everything but couldn't get it.

Comment: Show what you tried and what went wrong. And I guess your first "Output" is actually "Input"?

Comment: I answered a question like this earlier today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58369762/how-to-create-a-dictionary-merging-values-based-on-keys/58369804#58369804  (Except, instead of appending to the list, just keep hold onto the minimum value.)

Comment: It's not recommended to use list as a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
# Input list
a_list = [("1","111","15"),("2","111","10"),("3","111","5"),("4","112","40"),("5","112","10")]

# Sort the list by the third value (index-2)
sorted_list = sorted(a_list, key=lambda x: int(x[2]))

# Track visited and repeated elements to only add the first tuple(x) with the smallest x[1]
visited = []

# New list to only append unique tuples
new_list = []

for i in sorted_list:
    if i[1] not in visited:
        new_list.append(i)
        visited.append(i[1])
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[('1', '111', '15'), ('4', '112', '40')]
```

Comment: Thank you so much , worked perfectly,
Would you please explain this line sorted_list = sorted(a_list, key=lambda x: int(x[2])) ?

Comment: Sure. It sorts the list by the third element `x[2]` of the tuples inside. You can use `key` attribute of `sorted` function for such operations. Simply provide a function to the `key` attribute and it will do the rest. Check out this more detail [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-function-python/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from itertools import groupby

new_l = []
for k,v in groupby(list, lambda x: x[1]):
    new_l.append(min(filter(lambda x:x[1]==k, list), key=lambda x:int(x[2])))
```

`new_l` will be your output.

> Note that do not use pre-defiend names like `list` as a variable name. those names are mean something in python.

Comment: Thank you so much , worked perfectly,
I changed list to a_list in the question above

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility without importing, just because comprehension is fun:

```
lst = [("1","111","15"),("2","111","10"),("3","111","5"),("4","112","40"),("5","112","10")] 

[min((x for x in lst if x[1] == client), key=lambda x: int(x[2])) for client in {row[1] for row in lst}]
```

gives

```
 [('5', '112', '10'), ('3', '111', '5')]
```